# My update function in my controller is not run at all

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I created my model with this command `php artisan make:model BuildingOnRent -mcr` which created the controller and the resources.

In my `web.php`, I passed the resource route like this

**My web.php**

```
Route::resource('br', BuildingOnRentController::class);
```

In the controller scaffolded by Laravel herself, I added the code under the update function like this.

**My controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, BuildingOnRent $br)
    {
        echo $br;
        $request->validate([
            'purpose'=>'required',
            'rooms'=>'required',
            'bathrooms'=>'required',
            'parlour'=>'required',
            'rent_period'=>'required',
            'cost'=>'required',
            'city'=>'required',
            'state'=>'required',
            'locate'=>'required',
        ]);
        dd($br);
        $br->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('br.index')->with('success','Property updated successfully');
    }
```

**My edit.blade form action**

```
<form action="{{ route('br.update',['br'=>$br]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        // some html codes here
</form>
```

When I fill and submit the form in the `edit.blade`, hence triggering the update function in the controller, I am redirected to the route `br.index` but nothing is updated. In fact, the update code is not even run as I tried to `echo $br` and `dd($br)` but nothing was echoed or dumped. I take it that the update code is not run at all.

Why is the update code block not run?

How can I make it to run?

I am using laravel 10. Please help out.

Comment: What form method are you using? Needs to be `PUT` or `PATCH`

Comment: Yes, I did that with the same results. The update function is not run. I'll edit to reflect my actions so far.

Comment: You are missing `method="POST"` attribute/property in form

Comment: Thansk much @PragneshChauhan. I removed the `method="POST"` with the thought that the `@method('PUT')` was enough to do the trick. Please could you tell me why the form still needed `method="POST"` to work?

Comment: @Phyln Please read this article for more details https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have created a resource, For update you must pass `PATCH` or `PUT` method from form.

route:list give something like below

```
PUT|PATCH       br/{br} ........... br.update › BuildingOnRentController@update
```

Form:

```
<form action="{{ route('br.update', ['br' => $br]) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('put')
    
    {{-- some HTML --}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, I did that. I just didn't mention it in the question. It still did not run the update function.

Comment: Are you getting any error in log file? OR can you put `dd` at the top of the update method?

Comment: Thanks, brother. You ended a 4-day vicious circle for me.